# Which one of these words is more suitable for "having" or "accomplishing"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to express the achievement of a goal such as "Buying a car", or "Learning a Skill".
Can I say:

> "I obtained a new car."
>   or
>   "I obtained piano playing skill."

Is there a word better than *obtained* for expressing this, one that works both for acquiring a skill and acquiring property (the car)?

I'm looking for a word that combines both concepts, is commonly used, and is clearly understandable for both types of acquisitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *[acquire](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acquire#Verb)* works reasonably well, because it has a sense  “To get” that works well for getting a car, as well as a sense  “To gain, usually by one's own exertions; to get as one's own...” that works in both cases and particularly in the second, gaining a skill.

Among the set of near-synonyms *acquire, attain, earn, gain, obtain, procure, secure, win*, the first probably is most suited to serve both purposes.

Comment: great answer jwpat7. I appreciate it :) Thanks guys

Comment: @jwpat7 For a new car, I'd normally say *bought* unless I acquired it by other means (e.g. as a gift).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that *obtained* is **not the word you're looking for**. It's so vague, so three-day-old-beer flat, so general, that it says little.

Rather, I'd say:

> I **bought** a new car.
>   I **got** a new car **for my birthday**.
>   I **won** a new car **in a lottery**.

Use a vivid verb instead of something olive drab and camouflaged. However, *I obtained a new car* is grammatical, understandable, and boring. But it does invite questions: "How?", "Where ?", "When?", "From whom?"

The second case is just plain wrong. You can *acquire* a skill or a language, for example, but you can't *obtain* one. Those things aren't like advanced degrees -- it used to be that you had to **earn** a PhD, an Ma/MS, BA/BS, but now you can **obtain** them from dealers who print them and sell them to anyone willing to buy one.

I'd say:

> I **learned** how to play the piano.

Saying *"I obtained piano playing skill."* is like talking with wads of cotton stuffed in your nostrils. It can be done, but it makes the folks you're talking to feel strange and makes you sound even stranger.